# Free and concise statistics tutorials to give out as a refresher

Tags: references

Is anyone aware of a statistics resource (preferably 20 to 40 pages maximum) that reviews basic stats for people who took statistics classes already?

This resource could be handed out as a refresher to those who need it. The reason why I'm not looking for a book is that I find that people will more likely read a 20/40 pager than a 500 page book that goes into too much detail for the intended scope.

The ideal resource will explain the statistical methods, hypotheses, various methods, etc. It has to cover methods like Chi-squared. It has to be written in an easy to read and digest manner.

Comment: can you say a little more about the academic level of the course, the assumed mathematical and statistical background of the students, and the nature of the course for which the refresher is meant to be preparing students?

Comment: @JeromyAnglim - Mostly civil engineers and planners that need to understand the basic statistic concepts.

Answer (score 2):

I rather like Michael Lewis' little green book on [Data Analysis](http://books.google.com/books/about/Data_analysis.html?id=fqNa2QuCzd8C). Okay, it is not free and it has a bit more than 20/40 pages you are asking for, but with its 77 pages it is still 
far below the 500 pages benchmark. The book is easy to read and practically oriented.

In general the "little green books" are rather interesting for people working in social sciences. They are well written, offer an applied orientation, and yet they are rigorous. Note that these books are only appetizers. For the main dishes you will probably have to look elsewhere (although some people can eat themselves fill with appetizers ...).

Answer (score 2):

- I guess if it is an Engineering audience, then the freely available online [Engineering Statistics Handbook](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/) might be good. But I admit it's more content than you asked for.
- There's also this [probability and statistics cheat sheet](http://matthias.vallentin.net/probability-and-statistics-cookbook/)

Comment: This could be included as a further reading, rather than a mandatory one. Thanks for the link.